# Workflow Rule Runs Twice

Tags: process-builder, workflow, approval-process

The scenario is, there is a field called 'Expected closing Date' on the opportunity object. When the opportunity owner changes the expected closing date it should go for the approval of his manager. For this, I have written a workflow rule for storing the expected closing date before changing it because when the approver rejects the proposal then it should update for its original date, I have done it in rejection action of approval process(approval process fired by process builder) but it causes the workflow run again. I have set the flag true also in rejection but the user can change the date multiple times.
How I can avoid the recursiveness of the workflow rule in this scenario? Any help will be appreciated!

[image: Workflow Rule:]

[image: Approval Process]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one checkbox called "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" available under field update. Uncheck that checkbox so it won't fire the workflow if the date is changed via approval process rejection action.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kalpana! you solved my problem.

Comment: Any other reasons why this might happen? I'm seeing the same thing, but my process is already not recursive